# How to center 3 dots inside a Text component? <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 28}}>...</Text>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My goal is to center 3 dots inside a Text component for the React Navigation's header button.

[image]

```
            <Pressable
              style={({pressed}) => [
                {margin: 8, padding: 8, borderRadius: 16},
                !pressed && {backgroundColor: 'grey'},
              ]}>
              <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>...</Text>
            </Pressable>
```

What I've tried:

1. adding `flex: 1` to the Pressable component does the job.

[image]

2. However, adding `fontWeight: 'bold'` and `fontSize: '28'` ruin the view.

[image]

3. I've tried to add `justifyContent: 'center'` and `alignItems: 'center'`, it does vertically align the text for `a-zA-Z0-9`, but it does not vertically align the text for `...`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple text, use vector icons.

Example:

```js
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

//....


<Pressable
              style={({pressed}) => [
                {margin: 8, padding: 8, borderRadius: 16},
                !pressed && {backgroundColor: 'grey'},
              ]}>
              <Entypo name="dots-three-horizontal" size={24} color="black" />

            </Pressable>
```